# How to use intercpetors in Service folders?

Tags: java

I have a Interceptor called `CustomInterceptor` where I receive a `Long`

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String subTag = (req.getHeader("Accept-Language"));
        RestTemplate plantilla = new RestTemplate();
        Long resultado = plantilla.getForObject("", Long.class);
        return true;
    }
```

I am interested to recover this attribute on service layer where I send the number one.

```
@Service
public class SportService implements ISportService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SportService.class);

    @Autowired
    private SportTranslationRepository sportTranslationRepository;

    @Override
    public List<SportTranslation> retreiveListSports() {

        List<SportTranslation> sportTranslationList = sportTranslationRepository.retreiveSportByLanguage(1);
        return sportTranslationList;

    }

}
```

How I could receive the value of this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTTP interceptors on non-HTTP calls, but you can use `@Aspect` advice to do similar things.